# Showing a force is conservative by analyzing the curl of the vector

Tags: physics

I'm given a problem where I need to determine whether or not force $F$ is conservative, and verify by showing that it is equal to the gradient of potential $\nabla U$, for $F = (y, x, 0)$

I tried solving be verifying that $\nabla \times F = 0$, which I did using taking $\nabla \times F = (0-0)\hat{x} + (0-0)\hat{y} + (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_y-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_x)\hat{z}=(1-1)\hat{z}=0$ so by the curl method, F is conservative.

But when I took $U=-\int F_xdx-\int F_ydy=-\int ydx-\int xdy=-2xy$, where $\nabla U$ is clearly not $(y,x,0)$. I'm not sure how to deal with the 2 that pops up, and what my mistake is.

Comment: from where come the $2$ in your $U$.$U=-xy+constant$

Comment: I wrote $U=-\int ydx-\int xdy=-yx-xy=-2xy$ . I'm guessing I made a mistake here, but I don't know what

Comment: @George What makes you think $\int F_xdx + F_ydy = \int F_xdx + \int F_ydy$?

Comment: @George $U=-xy$  not  $U=-2xy$.

Comment: @Bye_World I'm not sure what the difference is there.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Yes I know that, since that would make the result consistent. What I'm asking is what I'm doing wrong calculating U.

Comment: @George The difference is that $\int F_xdx  + F_ydy$ is a line integral in $\Bbb R^2$ where $\int F_xdx + \int F_ydy$ is the sum of two one-dimensional integrals.  They are, in general, not the same.

Comment: Right thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: @George look now at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=-y$

so $U=-xy+f(y).$

and

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=-x$

so $U=-xy+g(x)$

thus

$f(y)=g(x)=C$

and

$U=-xy+C$.